# how to send json-rpc http post request over remote methods and passing encrypted params in java

Tags: java, json, spring, json-rpc

i am able to send the request over remote method using curl:
curl http://admin:@192.0.2.1/json_rpc --data `{"method":"ip.status.interface.ipv4.get","params":[],"id":"0"}`
but while sending it from my JsonRpc Service class i am getting

> com.googlecode.jsonrpc4j.HttpException: 
>   401 Not Authorized
>
> Authorization required to access this URL.
>
> ---
>
> Vitesse Web Server at 192.0.2.1 Port 80

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to hit the api via curl, your api setup doesnt seems to have any problem. Problem could be with your calling code (JsonRPC service). Please check if there is any proxy set on your JsonRPC service which might not be authorised to access 192.0.2.1 at port 80. Try to look at network level as you are able to call api via curl.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply..
where do i need to put my json object {"method":"ip.status.interface.ipv4.get","params":[],"id":"0"}
in the body or along with url while calling from my service class.

Comment: I guess it doesnt matters in your case. You are getting authorization error which has nothing to do with the way you post your data.I suggest again to look at any proxy settings in your system

Comment: proxy settings are all good. i am getting this error b'coz while  posting data from my java class data reaches to remote server as:-
{"id":"3878165270952444440","jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"testViteese","params":[]}
while posting data from curl data is:-
{"method":"ip.status.interface.ipv4.get","params":[],"id":"0"}
So, basicaly there is difference in json object. so plz tell me how to rectify this error.
method name ip.status.interface.ipv4.get is not valid in java. so i cant use this method name.
thanks

Comment: What is the error in java while using the other method name

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - void is an invalid type for the variable ip
 - Syntax error on token "interface", Identifier expected
 - Return type for the method is missing
 - Syntax error on token "get", Identifier expected after this 
  token
 - Syntax error on token "void", volatile expected

Comment: Thisi s clearly Java compilation issue. Its better if you share the few lines of code